# Key exchange during IKE_AUTH phase of IKEv2

Tags: diffie-hellman, ipsec

This is what a casual `IKEv2` handshake looks like :

```
  Initiator                                                       Responder
  |                                                                      |
 1|-----------------------> HDR, SAi1, KEi, Ni ------------------------->|
 2|<----------------- HDR, SAr1, KEr, Nr, [CERTREQ] <--------------------|
 3|----> HDR, SK {IDi, [CERT,] [CERTREQ,] [IDr,] AUTH, SAi2, TSi, TSr}-->| 
 4|<------------ HDR, SK {IDr, [CERT,] AUTH, SAr2, TSi, TSr} <-----------|
  |                                                                      |
```

Where messages (1) and (2) belong to `IKE_SA_INIT` exchange and messages (3) and (4) belong to `IKE_AUTH` exchange.
I have analyzed a wireshark trace of this exchange and it seems to me that during `IKE_AUTH (SAi2, SAr2)`, the initiator/the responder advertises the set of security algorithms it supports/it chooses respectively (encryption, authentication, integrity protection, diffie-hellman group). However neither of both does advertise its DH value. So there is no actual key exchange here. My question is for what purpose does the `(SAi2, SAr2)` security association negotiation serve? and why do we even need to have a second key exchange since the protocol already achieved one during `IKE_SA_INIT` (In other words why do we need to negotiate new keys) ?

Comment: cross-posted here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165232/key-exchange-during-ike-auth-phase-of-ikev2